# Automatically Bot display rating card after few seconds to take user feedback

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker, adaptive-cards

I have a bot made using framework v4 in c#. I want that my bot take user feedback once the bot goes idle, or in the case user doesn't responded to bot.I have made my card but not getting any logic to implement above mention feature in my bot. I am also attaching the code of card i made. Also the image of my card.
Can any look into it and help me out with this implementation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84ZS7.png)

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
{
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "size": "Medium",
  "weight": "Bolder",
  "color": "Accent",
  "text": "Rate your experience!"
},
{
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "separator": true,
  "text": "Please rate your experience! Your feedback is very appreciated and will help improve your experience in the future. ",
  "wrap": true
},
{
  "type": "ColumnSet",
  "spacing": "Medium",
  "columns": [
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "awful"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Awful"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "bad"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Bad"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "normal"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "normal"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "good"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Good"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "terrific"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Terrific"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "Input.Text",
  "id": "comment",
  "placeholder": "Add a comment",
  "isMultiline": true
}
 ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
   "actions":
[
  {
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "OK",
   // "data":  "ok"
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in way to do this, nor is there a "standard" suggestion. However, we typically recommend:

1. On each message, start an asynchronous timer. You can do this in the bot, but it would be better to do outside of the bot, like with Azure Functions or something. The rest of this answer will assume the timer is outside of the bot. Ensure the timer also keeps track of the [conversationReference](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/89817b6b8db42726c9ffcf82bf40b4e66592b84f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Schema/ConversationReference.cs) related to the timer.
2. Restart the timer each time the user matching that `conversationReference` sends a message
3. Once the timer expires, send an event to the bot with the user and conversation information (maybe through `ChannelData`), letting the bot know the timer has expired. You could also create a separate endpoint and monitor there, so you don't need the activity scheme; instead of `/api/messages`, you could use something like `/api/expiredTimers`.
4. Once the expired timer event is received, [send a proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to the user to either 1) see if they're still there, or 2) end the conversation.

Comment: i am not getting what you want so say..can suggest any easy way to implement it?

Comment: can explain in simple language ,,i am very new to development

Comment: @AmitKumar I'm afraid that I can't without putting several hours of work into writing the code. This isn't a simple thing to accomplish...at all. Alternatively, you could write a Feedback Dialog and call it once the user has completed a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the code that [ShowTypingMiddleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs)  uses.  Upon receiving a message activity, it then sets a timer, when the timer is triggered, execute your pro-active activity.

I just implemented this for a "are you still there?" functionality.  Pretty straightforward.

Just have to modify the SendTypingAsync to execute whatever activity you want to send to the user at that time.