# I want to sent a message from bot "Are you there after X mins" when their no further userinput to bot

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-functions, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am using Bot Framework v4 with c# and deploying to Slack channel. I want to create a timer in the bot or outside using Azure functions. In case of no user input for x mins, the bot should send a message like "Are you there?"

Having read many article on Internet I couldn't find the desired solution

I tired to follow this [Automatically Bot display rating card after few seconds to take user feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055694/automatically-bot-display-rating-card-after-few-seconds-to-take-user-feedback/60081476?noredirect=1#comment106292154_60081476)

but do not fully understand what this person says there. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Which channel are you using? I have an implementation using botframework-webchat (via directline, not the out of the box webchat you can embed in iframe) where you set up a timer on the page itself and it sends a back-channel message to the bot which triggers a message. But it won't work unless you can use the directline channel for botframework-webchat.

Comment: @billoverton i am using slack channel.but you share your solution that would be helpful

Comment: My solution will not work on Slack channel, but I'll provide it with some thoughts on how you could do something similar via Azure function (though I don't have direct experience with that)

Answer (score 1):

My method works for Directline Webchat, but you may be able to take this concept and use it in a solution that will work for Slack.

When using [botframework-webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), you are able to set up a custom store to track inactivity. In my example below, I'm using a combination of a page title "notification" with sending a message. But you could simply set the interval and send the message without any of the page title changes.

```js
           let interval;

            var PageTitleNotification = {
                Vars:{
                    OriginalTitle: document.title,
                    Interval: null
                },    
                On: function(notification, intervalSpeed){
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.Vars.Interval = setInterval(function(){
                        document.title = (_this.Vars.OriginalTitle == document.title)
                                 ? notification
                                 : _this.Vars.OriginalTitle;
                    }, (intervalSpeed) ? intervalSpeed : 1000);
                },
                Off: function(){
                    clearInterval(this.Vars.Interval);
                    document.title = this.Vars.OriginalTitle;   
                }
            }

            // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {

                if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE') {
                    // Message sent by the user
                    PageTitleNotification.Off();
                    clearTimeout(interval);
                } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' && action.payload.activity.name !== "inactive") {
                    // Message sent by the bot
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = setTimeout(() => {
                        // Change title to flash the page
                        PageTitleNotification.On('Are you still there?');

                        // Notify bot the user has been inactive
                        dispatch({
                            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                            payload: {
                                name: 'inactive',
                                value: ''
                            }
                        });
                    }, 300000)
                }

                return next(action);
            });
```

The challenge when you are using Slack channel is that you can't inject something like this on Slack client side, so you will need to do it externally. The best guidance I can give you is to start from the [proactive notification sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). You will need to get the conversation reference from turnContext via something like `turnContext.getConversationReference()` and store it. You can then send it to a function and start a timer. If the function doesn't receive another message for that reference during your specified time period, you can send the proactive message.

I think you would want to do this as a local function in your bot, not an Azure Function, because you want to reset the timer every time the user sends a new message. I'm not sure how you would keep track of that using an external Azure Function. Hopefully this will be enough to give you some ideas on implementing this functionality in Slack channel.